# boolean variable keeps changing to false

Tags: java, android, if-statement, boolean, sharedpreferences

In my app's settings, I have a checkbox that disables the back button when checked.
I'm using SharedPreferences for that.
but the problem is even when it's true, it changes to false when it's being checked in if-statement.

```
Boolean isLockedB;

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
isLockedB = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("block_back",false);
```

when I debug, it shows the isLockedB value as true, then in here:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)){
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
    }else {
        if (isLockedB == false){
            super.onBackPressed();
        }else {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

it shows that my isLockedB is false.

Comment: That code is not changing it, so you need to keep debugging and find out where it is being changed.

Answer (score 1):

Make `isLockedB` `static`. You're variable is likely being recycled and set back to the default state, which for a boolean is `false`

Or, what you should really be doing, is create a singleton class that contains your SharedPreferences values. That way if your singleton is null you will know to reload your preferences.

Answer (score -1):

```
private Editor _prefsEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
 _prefsEditor.putBoolean("block_back",true);
```

set value true if checkbox clicked else set false.It always gives you false because you have set false to its default value in below statement.

isLockedB = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("block_back",false);